# Start with Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I install Tornado 2.4, how i can run applications? I need install ngnix? in documentaton not write about running application!

i using ubuntu, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

create a python file server.py

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web

from tornado.options import define, options

define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")


def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

now you can start it with python!

```
python server.py
```

open your browser -->  `http://127.0.0.1:8888`

Answer (score 0):

Tornado is not an application you can run. It is a library for web services. You need to install a server that can run/serve Python. Then you can install the module, Tornado. Did you read the installation instructions?

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tornado

"On Python 2.6 and 2.7, it is also possible to simply add the tornado
directory to your PYTHONPATH instead of building with setup.py, since
the standard library includes epoll support."

All you need is the server configuration that supports CGI and has python installed. Like Apache or nginx. so, yes (kind of)
http://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html The first page of the documentation says it is not dependent on anything outsize of python-- well besides a functioning HTTP server, because that's how you access the scripts.